Audacity sometimes adds blank filler at the end of tracks: Why does this happen and how to stop this?
I often increase tempo of multiple MP3 files. Here's what I do:

Drag and drop files into Audacity (in Windows 11).
Ctrl+A (select all)
"Effect" > "Pitch and Tempo" > "Change Tempo..." > "Apply"

Usually, the above works nicely and as intended with no "blank filler" added:


But sometimes, weirdly, after increasing tempo, for each MP3, Audacity adds an additional blank filler so that the total time for each track is equal (and equal to the maximum time of the longest MP3 after conversion):

How do I stop this? And why does this happen?

@Destroy666: Did you try moving the longest to the top? Yes just tried:


Did you try moving the longest to the top? Which Audacity version?

@Destroy666: Which Audacity version? Audacity 3.7.1 // Did you try moving the longest to the top? Yes just tried, see above.
